# ServiceStack.Razor PartialViewResult equivalent?

Tags: servicestack, partials, servicestack-razor

Is there a way to return the ASP.NET MVC equivalent of a PartialViewResult (stand-alone partial) in ServiceStack.Razor?

In my service, I would like to return the response DTO as a rendered Partial as opposed to a complete View; again, I just need some rendered HTML snippets for this service.

The use case is to make an AJAX call to a service and then have the service returned the rendered partial.

In one of my views, I just tried the following, but it is still returning the full HTML markup and not just the small snippet.

inside travel.cshtml...

```
@model TravelScenarioResponse

@Model.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to not use any Layout with `@layout ""`, e.g:

```
@layout ""
@model TravelScenarioResponse

@Model.Name
```

Otherwise if you want the same view to be used with multiple layouts and as a partial you can add an [Views/Empty.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/Views/Shared/Empty.cshtml) that just contains:

```
@RenderBody()
```

And use that layout in any of the [View/Template overrides documented in EmailContacts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/EmailContacts/#view-model). E.g. you can decorate your Service or action with a `[ClientCanSwapTemplates]` attribute, e.g:

```
[ClientCanSwapTemplates]
public class MyService : Service { ... }
```

And then the client can specify what view they want to render service with, so you can view a partial by specifying `?Template=Empty` on the query string, e.g:

- http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?Template=Empty
- http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?View=AngularJS&Template=Empty
- http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?Template=SimpleLayout